# C++ - Fatal Error: circle.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I m new to C++ programming and I am getting an error on line 52 `"fatal error: circle.h: No such file or directory"`.  I am not sure what I am missing that it isn't recognized, can some help me understand what I am doing wrong here please?

My code is supposed to calculate the area of a circle and square and include header files (`Circle.h`, `Square.h`) and implementation files (`circle.cpp`, `Square.cpp` and `main.cpp`).

Thank you for any help as it is appreciated...

**circle.h:**

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

struct Circle  //circle structure class
{
public:
    Circle();  //declaration
    void setRadius(double r);  //setting the radius
    double getRadius(); //getting the radius
    double Area(); //getting calculated area of the circle
    void Display(); //display the output

protected:
    double Radius; //declaring the radius value

    private;
};

#endif
```

**square.h:**

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

struct Square  //square structure class
{
puble:
    Square();  //delcaration
    void setLength();  //setting the length
    double getLength();  //getting the length
    double Area(); //get the calculated area of the square
    void Display(); //display the output

protected :
    double Length;  //length value declaration

    private;
};

#endif
```

**circle.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circle.h"

using namespace std;

const double PI=3.14159;  //initializing the global values
Circle::Circle()  //method declaration
{
    Radius = 0; //initializing the radius value
}

void Circle::setRadius(double r)
{
    Radius = r<=0 ? 1 : r;  //check the input radius value
}

double Circle::getRadius()
{
    return Radius; //getting and setting the value
}

double Circle::Area()
{
    return Radius * Radius * PI;  //calculating and returning the area for the cirlce
}

void Circle::Display()  //display the data
{
    cout << "\nCircle Data";
    cout << "\nRadius = " <<getRadius();
    cout << "\nArea = "  <<Area() << "\n";
}
```

**square.cpp:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "square.h"

using namespace std;

Square::Square()  //method declaration
{
    Length = 0;  //initializing the length
}

void Square::setLength(double)
{
    Length = 1<=0 ? 1 : l;  //check the input length value
}

double Square::getLength()
{
    return Length;  //returning the length
}

double Square::Area()
{
    return Length * 4;  //calculate and return the area of the square
}

void Square::Display()
{
    cout << "n\Square Data";
    cout << "n\Length = " <getLength();
    cout << "n\Area = " << Area() << "n\";
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circle.h" //include the header file for circle
#include "square.h"  //include the header file for square

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int radius.length;
    Circle circle; //Displaying a circle using the default value of the radius
    circle Display();
    Circle circ; //This is the circle with the data entered for the radius

    cout << "Enter a radius value for the circle: " endl;  //Prompt the user to input the radius
    cin >> Radius;  //read the input

    circ setRadius (radius);
    circ Display();

    Square square;  //Displaying a square using the default value
    square Display();
    Square sqre; //This is the square with the data entered for the length

    cout << "Enter the length of one side of the square: " endl;  //Prompt the user to input the length
    cin >> length; //read the input

    sqre.setLength(length);  //from the base class
    sqre Display();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Believe the compiler when it tells you a file is not found.

Comment: What is your c++ compiler? gcc? llvm? Also on which OS?

Comment: If you are on linux or macos your filesystem may be case sensitive meaning Circle.h is different from circle.h

Comment: Do you really have an #include statement on line 52 of a file?

Comment: It's just  #include "circle.h" to #include "Circle.h" fix.

Comment: I have #include "circle.h" on line 52, but I still don't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the error you show. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] where you add a comment on the line where you get the error. And please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error or build output into the question as well.

Comment: My c compiler is gcc

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment, the code you show have so many other errors that your build output should be quite a long list of errors. It's really important to create a [mcve] which replicate the problem you ask about, and don't contain other unrelated problems.

Comment: Sorry as I said I am new so I wasn't sure what to include with regards to the portion of program that might need to be viewed to help identify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For "MRE", a small program with only main.cpp, circle.h, circle.cpp and try to reproduce the problem. Since it's complaining about include, even no code in body of `main` should reproduce it.

Comment: ***portion of program that might need to be viewed to help identify what I am doing wrong*** I expect you will have to solve this yourself. My advice is to not write so much code without compiling and testing. It's very obvious that you did not do much compiling yet. To solve the problem with the current code you may want to create a new project in a new folder and add small parts of your code and compile and test.

Comment: I assume that circle.h is in the same folder as circle.cpp, square.cpp and the rest of the headers and source files.

Comment: @AnnetteKitz The first step in creating a [mre] is often copying your project. Then work with that copy (leaving your "real" project untouched). Strip out about half the code and re-compile. If the first error produced by the compiler changes, put that code back and strip out the other half. Repeat until the code is minimal. More or less -- don't take "half" too literally. **For this particular error** the minimal code is probably `Circle.h` reduced to just the first, second, and last lines (the include guard), `circle.cpp` reduced to just the line that includes `Circle.h`, and no other files.

Comment: The problem is that beginners don't have the skills or confidence or understanding necessary to produce minimal reproducable examples.

Comment: @AnnetteKitz The main lesson here is the one mentioned by drescherjm. You've written too much code with too little testing. The correct way to program is to write a few lines of code, and then test what you have written. Only when it is working do you write some more lines of code. That is how expereinced programmers work, It's only beginners who try to write fifty lines of code in one go.

Answer (score 0):

First, list the files and check the spelling (on linux):

```
ls -l
```

Rename/save your main.cpp, and replace with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circle.h" //include the header file for circle
#include "square.h"  //include the header file for square

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Circle circle; // create a default circle
    circle.Display(); //Display circle using the default values

    Square square; // create a default square
    square.Display(); //Display square using the default values

    return 0;
}
```

If that gives the same error, then try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h" //include the header file for circle
#include "Square.h"  //include the header file for square

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Circle circle; // create a default circle
    circle.Display(); //Display circle using the default values

    Square square; // create a default square
    square.Display(); //Display square using the default values

    return 0;
}
```